# Looking for analytic functions $f,g,h$, such that $f(x+y)=g(x)+h(y)$ and at least $g$ or $h$ nonlinear

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations, nonlinear-analysis

I'm looking for 3 analytic, continuous functions $f,g$ and $h$, all mapping $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, such that
$$f(x+y)=g(x)+h(y)$$
On one hand, I think; this is not possible, as it fights the property of linearity. But on the otherhand, since $g$ and $h$ are not the same as $f$ (perse), the linearity property maybe is not ruining the fun here...

Does one of you maybe know an example? (or show that this is not possible)

I found some relating questions, however, these asked for a function $f$ that satisfies the property $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$, which I don't require

Comment: Just put $y=0$ or $x=0$ in your relation and see what happens.

Comment: Great! I guess this was the last bit I needed. My result is that if it is assumed that $f(0)=0$, then $g$ and $h$ _must_ be equivalent to $f$...

Comment: @seaver I'm unclear about the significance of assuming that $f(0) = 0.$  Further, I have trouble using Rigel's comment to solve the problem.  It may be that Rigel is hinting at what I'm about to say.  WLOG g is a linear function.  As a direct consequence of your constraint, for any $x,y, g(x) - g(y) = h(x) - h(y).$  It seems to me that this, coupled with the assumption that g is linear means that h must also be linear.

Comment: first note that it should be that $f(0)=h(0)+g(0)$. What I then did was: $f(0+y)+f(x+0)=g(0)+h(y)+g(x)+h(0) = f(0)+f(x+y)$ (by my definition) I'm only not sure how to 'remove' the f(0) term (in my problem I have this assumption on beforehand, so it does not matter). I'm not sure why you say WLOG, because in my eyes there is some loss when you assume that :P.

Comment: @seaver first of all: good catch, I **misread** your problem.  I agree, my assumption that one of g or h is linear is **unwarranted.**  Second of all, now that you have explained your reasoning re the query that you **actually** posed, I realize that the reason that I'm having trouble here is because I have virtually no experience "scrutinizing" analytic functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have :

$$
f(x+y)=g(x)+h(y) \tag{1}
$$

Taking $y=0$ in (1) above, we deduce

$$
g(x)=f(x)-h(0) \tag{2}
$$

Plugging back (2) into (1), we find

$$
f(x+y)=f(x)+h(y)-h(0) \tag{3}
$$

Taking $x=0$ in (3) above, we have

$$
h(y)=f(y)-f(0)+h(0) \tag{4}
$$

Plugging back (4) into (3), we find

$$
f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)-f(0) \tag{5}
$$

If we put $F(x)=f(x)-f(0)$, we can rewrite (5) as

$$
F(x+y)=F(x)+F(y) \tag{6}
$$

Since $F$ is continuous, $F$ is linear and $f$ is affine.
Note that you don't need analyticity, you just need continuity.